# I cannot access http://localhost:8000/accounts/profile

Tags: python, html, django

I cannot access `http://localhost:8000/accounts/profile`. When I access this address, it sends me to `http://localhost:8000/accounts/login/?next=/accounts/profile/`. I really cannot understand why. I wrote in `urls.py`.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^detail$', views.detail,name='detail'),
    url(r'^login/$', views.login,name='login'),
    url(r'^profile/$', views.profile, name='profile'),
]
```

in `views.py`

```
def login(request):
    login_form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    regist_form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    if regist_form.is_valid():
        user = regist_form.save(commit=False)
        context = {
            'user': request.user,
            'login_form': login_form,
            'regist_form': regist_form,
        }

        return redirect('profile', context)

    if login_form.is_valid():
        user = login_form.save(commit=False)
        login(request, user)
        context = {
            'user': request.user,
            'login_form': login_form,
            'regist_form': regist_form,
        }
        return redirect('profile', context)

    context = {
        'login_form': login_form,
        'regist_form': regist_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/login.html', context)

def profile(request):
    context = {
        'user': request.user,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/profile.html', context)
```

in html

```
<main>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="detailimg col-xs-12">
                <img class="small_img" src="{% static 'detail.jpg' %}" alt="Detail" />
                <div class="absolute-fill vertical-center-container">
                    <p class="hthree">XXX
                        <span class="hthree_small">
                            <br>YYY
                            <br>ZZZ</span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="bodyele  col-xs-12">
                <a class="button-primary" href="{% url 'accounts:profile' %}">Profile</a>
                <a class="button-primary" href="{% url 'accounts:kenshinresults' %}">See</a>
                <a class="button-primary" href="{% url 'accounts:kenshinresults' %}">Know</a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

When i put Profile tag, this happens. What is wrong in my code?
 `urls.py`, `views.py` & html are in accounts.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` in **project settings.py**

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL ='/'
```

And it should work fine for you.

Comment: I wrote in these code, but same error happens.What should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You must delete `return redirect('profile', context)` and replace `return context` and set

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL ='/'
```

in your settings.py file.

I think this must solve your problem.